# Rsyslog behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, rsyslog

I am using a monitoring software to monitor my infrastructure and I'd like to use rsyslog to forward logs of my database server to it.
But my problem is the following, I am behind a proxy. And I didn't find anything about rsyslog behind a proxy. I got a time out while trying to my monitoring app.
How can I set rsyslog to send the data using the proxy configuration (if is it even possible) ?

Thanks,

I tried to set the proxies environment variable (HTTP(S)_PROXY and http(s)_proxy) system wide, and even set them inside rsyslog service file, but no way to get it working.